# How to extract values from nested dictionary using postgresql command?

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, postgresql-9.5

I am using postgresql to extract some data from my database.One of the query i hit returns a nested dictionary to me for a specific date i have specified.
For eg:

```
query: select user_position_details from user_detail where last_login >= '2018-03-01';
```

This query return the follwing result:

```
 "{\"user_position\": {\"LOGIN_s\": \"something\", \"X_SLS_AREA_s\": \"data\"}}"
"{\"user_position\": {\"LOGIN_so\": \"login_data\", \"X_SLS_AREA_s\": \"data\"}}"
```

I want only the field LOGIN_s out of this nested dictionay.
Is there any way i can do this using a specific query?
I have searched about this but could not find anything that would help.

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a json string output. Use the `json module` to convert it to JSON and access the required value using key.

**Ex:**

```
import json
s = ["{\"user_position\": {\"LOGIN_so\": \"something\", \"X_SLS_AREA_s\": \"data\"}}",
"{\"user_position\": {\"LOGIN_so\": \"login_data\", \"X_SLS_AREA_s\": \"data\"}}"]

for i in s:
    v = json.loads(i)
    print(v["user_position"].get(u'LOGIN_so'))
```

Comment: How can I use json module? I am doing this on ubuntu terminal. I used to_json(user_position_details).